# Cross orgin error in google chrome for the api call

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, angular

in the nodejs backend i have added this code to the server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

but in angularjs 2 client side in google chrome is throwing this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/team. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

this is the service code for angular2 i'm using

```
export class DataService {
    // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http, private _configuration: Configuration,private team:Team) {

        //this.actionUrl = _configuration.ServerWithApiUrl;
        this.actionUrl = "http://localhost:8080/team";

    }
    private actionUrl: string;

    addData(postData: Team): Observable<Team[]> {

        //let body = JSON.stringify({ Team });
        this.team = postData;
        console.log(this.team);
        let body = JSON.stringify({ postData });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log(body);

        return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

For your new error message: Angular2 is lower-casing the headers.
Please update your backend to accept `content-type` too.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, content-type, Accept");
```

You cant test post's to this URL: http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=anyNameYouWillFind

And can see your posts there: http://posttestserver.com/data/

Browse to year, month, day and anyNameYouWillFind ..

**OLD:**

you have to prefix your url!!

this.http.get('**http**://localhost:8080/v1_user/45646/team');

Comment: you mean i have to add "http://localhost:8080/v1_user/45646/team" this url at client side right??

Comment: pls post your Angular2 get method.

Comment: But in your error message is another URL.. localhost:8080/v1_user/45646/team instead of localhost:8080/team as in your question..

Comment: ya i have updated according to your answer the error has been changed

Comment: angular is lower-casing the headers, please update your backend to allow `content-type` too.

Comment: i'm getting this error now `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/v1_user/45646/team. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`

Comment: I am not sure if its an Angular2 problem or your backend.. please test posting to this URL: `http://posttestserver.com/post.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding this to the backend node.js

```
// access control --> allowed all origin
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    next();
})

.options('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.end();
})
;
```